ssh fails only when multiple arguments are stored in a string
I am writing a bash script on Raspberry Pi OS (based on Debian 12 Bookworm). The script tries to do something like
ssh "$args" "$user"@"$ip" 'command'
From what I have read this is a standard practice. However I have found that when $args contains more than one argument, such as
-v -i /path/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes
and then executing
ssh "$args" "$user"@"$ip" 'echo "Success in logging into $HOSTNAME"'
ssh returns the following with an exit status of 255:
unknown option --
 usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface] 
            [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
            [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
            [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
            [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
            [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
            [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command [argument ...]]

However executing the same command by using just the contents of $args intead of using $args succeeds and exits with a status of 0:
ssh -v -i /path/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes "$user"@"$ip" 'echo "Success in logging into $HOSTNAME"'
To restate, using $args works perfectly well when there is only a single argument, such as
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes
What is going on here? What can I do to prevent this? From the unknown option -- it would seem that something is parsing $args and stripping some things out of it, because it only complains about this when there are two or more arguments (two incidences of - in $args)?

You really shouldn't rely on word splitting of an unquoted parameter expansion in this way - for some better options see How can we run a command stored in a variable?

See my answer to ‘‘Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells’’.

Are you sure you're using bash and not zsh? zsh doesn't wordsplit after variable expansion, which would cause your problem

It works fine on my machine. Are you sure you put the correct variable? You mentioned $args but latter $arg, those might contain different values, hence unexpected result.

Thanks everyone for the feedback. I actually do have the variables quoted, I missed that when writing my examples in this post. I have fixed it, and also fixed the inconsistencies in arg/args. Does the updated post change your feedback?

I think it's a feature of (some implementation(s) of) ssh it allows -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes to be one word. It's totally expected -v -i /path/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes doesn't work when being one word, does work as multiple words. In Bash you get exactly one word from a double-quoted non-array shell variable.

and When is double-quoting necessary?

"this is a standard practice" - it's oft repeated bad practice. Use an array instead

(I should probably just close this as a duplicate, but let's try to explain the particular case anyway.)
The quoted expansion "$args" produces one argument, so in effect you're running ssh "-v -i /path/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes" .... The spaces and dashes there are taken as option characters, similarly to how stacked options work in the more useful cases like -abc. The dash is not a valid option, so you get a complaint.
If ssh "$args" seems to work with args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes', that's probably because the parser for -o ignores whitespace (similarly to how whitespace in ssh_config is ignored). Try the same with args='-i /path/to/keyfile' and you're likely to get a file not found error, since you just included a leading space in the filename. (args='-i/path/to/keyfile' without the space would work, of course.)
See:

How can we run a command stored in a variable?
When is double-quoting necessary?
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting


FWIW, ssh "$args" would work in the yash shell if args was defined as args=(-v -i /path/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes) as "$args" there when $args is an array works like the "${args[@]}" of Korn-like shells (while "$args" in ksh/bash is "${args[0]}" and in zsh "${args[*]}").

@ilkkachu This explains the issue excellently thank you! What I've learned here is that some packages parse arguments stored in strings as single arguments. I would have caught this myself if it hadn't been for the -o ... case exception. The technique I described works perfectly well for every package I've ever had to script including tar, pbzip2, rsync, and so on. So now I'm aware of a parser variant that I hadn't been before. Thanks for the help in understanding this one.

@jitter, I would be surprised to see something like args='-a foo -b -c'; somecmd "$args" work as giving three options with any tool. The same with somecmd $args would work in many cases, but it has caveats the moment you need to pass strings that actually contain whitespace. (and it's a FAQ, too) The quotes make a difference, and like comments above hint, the differences between shells also matter. Mostly Bash vs. zsh, as I expect those are the ones one is most likely to expect without explicitly choosing which shell to run.
